# How can I connect a libvirt KVM virtual machine to be connected to my Wireless home?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, vagrant, libvirt

How can I connect a libvirt KVM virtual machine to be connected to my Wireless home? (After it is created already)

I want it to be assigned an IP of my wireless network.

Note: I have Ubuntu 16. (Also I'm using vagrant to do that but the "public network" property doesn't seem to be working it says that it doesn't find eth0 so i'm trying to connect the vm to the wireless network manually first without vagrant and hopefully automate it with vagrant later on if i figured it out)

Please help me I am a beginner in Linux if anyone can provide me with the exact details and commands I would be very grateful.

Thanks.